# What's the difference between transfer-response and forward-request errors in API management?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics

A large number requests over our Azure API Management result in the `ClientConnectionFailure` exception.

By querying the logs I see two variants of the error:

```
exceptions
| where cloud_RoleName == "..." 
| summarize num = count(itemCount) by problemId, outerMessage 
| order by num
```

1. **problemId**: ClientConnectionFailure at transfer-response, **outermessage**: A task was canceled, **count** 403,249
2. **problemId**: ClientConnectionFailure at forward-request, **outermessage**: The operation was canceled, **count** 55,531

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862256/api-management-service-clientconnectionfailure-at-forward-request), the problem could be time-outs or that clients abandon connections. With response times generally within 500ms I'm inclined to rule out the first.

The question is: what is the difference between transfer-response and forward-request, and does it provide any clues as to what is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Transfer-response** means that the client dropped the connection after it started receiving the response.

**Forward-request** means that the client dropped the connection while the APIM gateway was sending the request to the back end or waiting for a response from the back end.